# IDE suggestions for Linux Development

Tags: ide, linux

Before you answer **vi**...
I'm looking to set a development environment for programmers with mainly Windows/Visual Studio background. Of course Emacs and Eclipse come to mind as IDEs, any other useful tips? thanks

Comment: Re-tagged, 'linux' is quite different from 'linux kernel', this belongs in linux-kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the editor is incidental. Just read the kernel coding standards on tabs, indentation, functions vs keywords, use of braces, etc .. and it doesn't matter WHAT editor you use.

If you think your choice of editor is somehow going to improve your code or help you get into 'the zone' .. you probably aren't ready to send patches. git-send-patch exists because so many use a plethora of different editors.

If you kidnapped me and sat me down in front of any version of emacs then pointed a gun to my head and told me to code, I'd ask you to just shoot me. I have nothing against emacs, in fact I still have one of the few surviving copies on tape which I paid $50 to get a long time ago.

Use an editor that lets you focus, simple and agreeable syntax highlighting, good editing functions, sensible keyboard shortcuts .. a handy snippet gallery and the rest is up to you.

Or, will a Chevy improve your driving over a Toyota (had to put a straw man argument in there somewhere, after all, this is debating Linux development)

In the spirit of that, I'm now going to re-tag your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are doing Linux Kernel work, perhaps you will be interested in Mr Torvalds [opinion of emacs](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=122955159617722&w=2)...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Linus FAQ](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/linus/) he uses MicroEmacs. :-)

Comment: I wonder what he has in his .emacs file because vanilla, that is one unusable editor!